# How to render like this - toon but with fuzzy edges?

Tags: rendering, shaders, eevee-render-engine

Alright, trying out toon rendering styles trying to match this (Puddles from Short Circuit by Disney):

[image]

Ive tried out various toon shaders including https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpWI2rU8iF0&t=1186s , and these have been helpful, however I need to know how this particular toon shading was done, with the "fuzzy" crayon edges:

[image]

Is this possible in Blender eevee?